# Can anyone please check why I am not getting signals and getting "Undeclared identifier" errors

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to plot signals on crossover(DIminus and DIPlus)  using indicator available in Tradingview...ADX and DI by Masanakam.

My additional conditions to the Indicator for strategy building and signals to be generated are:  the longcondition and shortcondition

```m
//@version=3
strategy("ADX and DI", overlay=true)
len = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=14)
th = input(title="threshold", type=integer, defval=20)

TrueRange = max(max(high-low, abs(high-nz(close[1]))), abs(low-nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0rueRange = max(max(high-low, abs(high-nz(close[1]))), abs(low-nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0

SmoothedTrueRange = nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus

DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DX = abs(DIPlus-DIMinus) / (DIPlus+DIMinus)*100
ADX = sma(DX, len)

longCondition = crossover(DIPlus, DIMinus)
if (longCondition and time>timestamp(2019, 01, 01, 09, 30)) 
strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossover(DIMinus, DIPlus)
if (shortCondition and time>timestamp(2019, 01, 01, 09, 30)) 
strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

The errors that I get are:

> Undeclared Identifier "SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus"
>   
>   Undeclared Identifier "SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus"
>   
>   Undeclared Identifier "SmoothedTrueRange"
>   
>   Undeclared Identifier "DIPlus"
>   
>   Undeclared Identifier "DIMinus"
>   
>   Undeclared Identifier "longCondition"
>   
>   Undeclared Identifier "shortCondition"